# How can I find a large petrology dataset?

Tags: petrology, open-data, database

I need a large dataset of the oxide components of peridotitic rocks and their manual classification for a project of mine. The only one that I managed to find was from the EarthChem database and it is too small, having only around 1700 useable samples. Does anyone have an idea of where I can find a larger dataset (>10,000 samples)?

Comment: Which databases from EarthChem did you look at? PetDB? SESAR?

Comment: I am not sure, I was given this database from my professor and she said it was from earthchem. this is my data if it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnTJgNfKPBpR1pMZHQwLVV2cVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So you can try going to that database yourself and see if you can get a better database.

Comment: from PetDB or SESAR?